# EF6 with SQLite in .NET 4.0 Code-Based Configuration: "Unable to Determine the DbProviderFactory"

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get EF6 Code-Based Configuration to work with SQLite in .NET 4.0. In my target application `App.config` is auto-generated so editing that is very painful. Initially when installing EF6 to SQLite through NuGet to my test application it generates the following **configuration that works**:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

On SQL Server CE I was able to just copy the contents of the `App.config` to a DbConfiguration class. Similarly I tried:

```
class DBConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public DBConfig() : base()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));

        this.SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        this.SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);

        this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
    }
}
```

But when creating the Context by giving the constructor SQLiteConnection or connectionString this yields me the System.NotSupportedException:

> Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

```
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Net40DefaultDbProviderFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetProviderFactory>b__0(Type t)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func'2 valueFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Net40DefaultDbProviderFactoryResolver.GetProviderFactory(DbConnection connection, IEnumerable'1 dataRows)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Net40DefaultDbProviderFactoryResolver.ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Add(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

I have tried:

- adding `SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));` 
  according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31800310/6033795).
- adding `AddDependencyResolver(new SingletonDependencyResolver<DbProviderFactory>(SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance));`
   and DependencyResolvers for DbProviderServices and IDbConnectionFactory and even tried setting them ad DefaultResolvers.
- creating my own SQLiteConnectionFactory and setting it as default according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935665).

I remember reading somewhere that if there is a `<System.Data>` section in `Machine.config` file it may cause confusion in the ProviderFactories. Is there any code-based configuration equivalent to `<remove invariant="" />`?

Also the SQLiteProviderService class is internal and the only way to get is through reflection according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23237737/6033795). Is the program truly able to access the service? This seems to work for most people though.

Any help or ideas to try and solve this well appreciated!

---

A curious note: when creating a SQLiteConnection from `SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.CreateConnection()` the DbProviderFactory property of the connection is `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory` but with the working `App.config` configuration `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderFactory(connection)` returns `SQLiteProviderFactory`. Whereas with code-based configuration it throws.

Comment: Change the default connection factory to be SQLite?

Comment: Is there a pre-built connection factory? I couldn't find any so I created my own following the answer from one of the links and set that as default. No success there.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319930/sqlite-entity-framework-without-app-config) I found suggestion that helped me configure sqlite with EF6 programatically.

Code block from that answer:

```
var dataRow = dbProviderFactoriesDataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemArray[2].ToString() == assemblyName);

if (dataRow != null)
    dbProviderFactoriesDataTable.Rows.Remove(dataRow);
```

is equivalent to:

```
<remove invariant="" />
```